# bulk update local json file with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file name `emoji.json` located in my local mac PC
my JSON file has this structure

```
[
{
    "name": "COPYRIGHT SIGN",
    "unified": "00A9-FE0F",
    "non_qualified": "00A9",
    "docomo": "E731",
    "au": "E558",
    "softbank": "E24E",
    "google": "FEB29",
    "image": "00a9-fe0f.png",
    "sheet_x": 0,
    "sheet_y": 12,
    "s": "copyright",
    "short_names": [
        "copyright"
    ],
    "text": null,
    "texts": null,
    "c": "Symbols",
    "o": 128,
    "added_in": "1.1",
    "has_img_twitter": false,
    "has_img_emojione": false,
    "has_img_messenger": false
},
{
    "name": "REGISTERED SIGN",
    "unified": "00AE-FE0F",
    "non_qualified": "00AE",
    "docomo": "E736",
    "au": "E559",
    "softbank": "E24F",
    "google": "FEB2D",
    "image": "00ae-fe0f.png",
    "sheet_x": 0,
    "sheet_y": 13,
    "s": "registered",
    "short_names": [
        "registered"
    ],
    "text": null,
    "texts": null,
    "c": "Symbols",
    "o": 129,
    "added_in": "1.1",
    "has_img_twitter": false,
    "has_img_emojione": false,
    "has_img_messenger": false
}
...
]
```

and i want to remove some unwanted values so the file should became like blow.
and i want to save this file in JSON format in my PC

```
[
  {
    "s": "copyright",
    "c": "Symbols",
    "o": 128
  },
  {
    "s": "registered",
    "c": "Symbols",
    "o": 129
  }
]
```

i know JQ could do that and i check documentation and https://jqplay.org/
and i test and found out `map({ s, c , o })` could do that but i dint find how to input file and export file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jq` + `mv` approach:

```
jq 'map({s, c, o})' emoji.json > tmp_json && mv tmp_json emoji.json
```